# Which movie/TV show has an evil cyborg harvesting eyes from androids in a hidden town?

Tags: story-identification, movie, cyborg, androids

I watched it maybe more than 8 to 12 years ago, but as far as I remember there was this place where androids (or maybe they were cyborgs) lived. (I think it was more like a hidden town). This guy finds them by accident (or at least I remember it that way) and tries to help them. I don't remember seeing any aliens or spaceships or anything like that. It was live-action, and I think US-based.

So, what I remember:

- The bad guy is a human who has one red flashy robotic eye (not like terminators, it looks like a square eye patch above one of his eyes that functions like a second eye), he is collecting eyes from these androids/cyborgs. He also kills some of these androids/cyborgs but not all of them, some of them he just collects their eyes and doesn't kill (or get to kill).
- There was this woman who was a sexbot or something, she tried to give pleasure to the bad guy at some point, yet the bad guy added one of her eyes to his collection instead, but didn't/wasn't able to kill her. Towards the end she says something like "I used to give pleasure, now I only want to give pain"
- The human guy who found them tried to help them defend themselves from the bad guys, but they were in bad shape, many of them needed repair. To repair some of them, they needed spare parts they didn't seem to have, but one of the android/cyborg dudes said something like "we don't really bury our dead" and he brought a box of spare parts (or maybe android/cyborg body parts), they used these parts to repair some of the androids/cyborgs.
- There was this android/cyborg guy who was an assassin or something, but lost his fingers or hands, they couldn't find any hands compatible to his, but he said something like "I can still feel my trigger finger, just attach the weapons to my hands".

I remember it as a great movie/tv show, but I can't find anything about it. Can someone help me?

Please and thank you in advance...

Comment: This was live action, right (not a cartoon) and in English? Was it from / shown in the US?

Comment: It wasn't a cartoon, I'm not entirely certain if it was in English or if it was shown in US, but i think it was a US based show.

Comment: You need help writing better question titles.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure it is better now, but still no one seems to have any ideas other than how my post should be fixed. I feel like i will never be able to find this movie/tv show.. Thanks anyway..

Comment: @thefinder: aaaaaand it’s answered. Maybe it would have been anyway, but it doesn’t hurt to reduce the effort required for people to recognise what you’re looking for. Being direct is better.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[image: Cyborg 3 The Recycler (1994) - Movie Poster]

[**Cyborg 3: The Recycler** (1994)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0112765/)

Here's a brief synopsis of sorts :-)

> Set in a desolate post apocalyptic world where a once thriving golden
>   age of man and cyborgs has ended. Cyborgs are now hunted for their
>   parts.
>
> Cash, a female cyborg learns from Doc Edford that she is somehow
>   pregnant.
>
> She searches for the fabled city of Cytown to find Evans, a creator of
>   cyborgs, to find out more about her condition. She is followed by
>   Anton Lewellyn and his assistant Jocko.
>
> Lewellyn makes a living hunting cyborgs for their parts. Though he has
>   long wanted to find Cytown (the last haven for cyborgs), he becomes
>   obsessed in getting Cash and her child.

[image: Cyborg 3 - The Recycler (1994) - Pic 01]

That fellow in the pic fits your bad guy's description. One reviewer said:

> Played by the B-Movie staple of Richard Lynch, Anton Lewlleyn is a
>   human with a cyborg eye, a necklace of eyes and a jaunty bowler hat.
>   So we now know what kind of post-apocalypse we are in.

The scene where he retrieves the "sexbot's" eye(s):

> Now Lewellyn enters an establishment, the Cyberdello, in search of some Mechano
>   Whore action.
>
> He spies a cyber-hooker that catches his eye, Alexia.
>
> In a private room a little later, he catches her eye in a rather more
>   literal sense.

Read more reviews [here](http://www.dead4movie.com/cyborg-3-recycler/) and [here](http://www.mattmovieguy.com/2009/03/cyborg-3-recycler-1994.html). If you have issues with the YouTube video (might be country-locked), go [here](http://kinobanda.net/film/10138/) for an alternate version. It's a Russian dub, but should help you verify the movie :-)

<sup>*~ Reviews edited from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyborg_3:_The_Recycler), [Sunday B-Movies](http://sundaybmovies.wordpress.com/2011/02/13/cyborg-3-the-recycler-1995/) and [theOneliner.com](http://www.theoneliner.com/film76.html)*</sup>