# Movie about robots who can get pregnant and motorcycles throwing their drivers in the air

Tags: story-identification, movie, robots

I believe this is an old movie, since I watched it 10+ years ago. The story is about a robot (female robot) who is pregnant with—I'm not sure, a robot or human baby.

The opening sequence is pretty similar to *Future World* (2018), where there are motorcycles cruising the desert. However, after near the compound, those motorcycles suddenly stopped and threw their drivers in the air because of an anti-electronic measure of some sort.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=puYIvZ2umio?

Comment: The first thing this brought to my mind was Armitage (Armitage III and Dual Matrix.) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Armitage_III

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pretty sure you're looking for [Cyborg 3: The Recycler](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0112765/) from 1994.

> Cash, the heroine of Cyborg 2, is living safe in the free zone. But not for long. Biomechanical problems are taking down her systems and a visit to a doctor in Silica confirms her worst fears. **She is more then a marvel of cyborg technology. She is the first of her kind to become a creator - she is pregnant.**

Features a desert setting, a compound, *lots* of bikers, and a force field that disables their vehicles. Here's the trailer:

Comment: If accepted, it would be a dupe of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/49940/which-movie-tv-show-has-an-evil-cyborg-harvesting-eyes-from-androids-in-a-hidden/49946#49946

Comment: Thank you Walt, this is what I was looking for! @FuzzyBoots, I've looked at your linked Q and I don't think this is a dupe of that. Although, if an admin thinks it is, they're free to merge this one. I've not problem with that :)

Comment: @ariefbayu It's part of site policy that if two `story-identification` questions have the same answer, one is the dupe of the other.

Comment: It won't hurt your question. It just means that we already have an answer and it makes it easier to link them in the system.

Comment: Ah, I see. But seriously, I don't mind if this question marked as dupe and I lost my reps.

Answer (score 4):

Could this be *[Karate-Robo Zaborgar](https://www.cracked.com/blog/the-craziest-karate-robot-motorcycle-movie-ever-made/)*?

> The basic plot is that there's a loose-cannon cop named Yutaka Daimon who rides around on a motorcycle kicking the living crap out of Sigma, an organization of criminal cyborgs. His secret weapon: his motorcycle, which is actually a transforming robot that knows karate, has a machine gun in its mouth, and shoots remote control helicopters and cars with drills on the front out of its head and feet, respectively.

....

> Not two minutes after Daimon and Miss Borg are finished consummating their relationship, her stomach starts glowing, which I think we all recognize as a sure sign of half-robot pregnancy. Unfortunately, there's a battle not long after where Daimon is forced to choose between love and justice, causing Zaborgar to gain sentience and self-destruct while bear-hugging Miss Borg.

### Trailer

Answer (score 1):

The "pregnant robot" theme reminds me of *Batteries Not Included*, which refers to a robot child which is apparently stillborn.  The robots are more akin to small pets than androids.

I don't think this movie involved motorcycles to any significant extent, though.